# spring cloud config with profile jdbc deployed with legacy tomcat and other applications with dev profile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Spring cloud config requires the profile jdbc when using a database to store configurations. I'm looking to deploy the config app on an old legacy tomcat server with the jdbc profile. This appears to be fine until I need to deploy another springboot app with the dev/prod profile.

How do I deploy config with jdbc and every other app with dev or prod profile?

Comment: Why does the dev/prod profile make a difference?

Comment: @Spencergibb When I set setenv.sh within tomcat to dev, JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev" and then set active profile in my config service to jdbc, it does not override the setenv.sh profile. When I programmatically set the profile to jdbc within the SpringBootServletInitializer for the config app, the config app finally comes up correctly, however when I redeploy another dev service, it's now looking for jdbc rather than dev.

Comment: spring.profiles.active is not additive, you need to set all profiles with a comma-separated list.

Comment: @spencergibb are you referring to a comma separated list within the java_opts?

Comment: `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,jdbc` for example

Comment: @spencergibb so this worked, but with a gotcha.. if I deploy to tomcat the config app requiring the jdbc profile first followed by the others requiring dev profiles, everything works as desired. If I undeploy the config app and then attempt to redeploy it, it will no longer use the jdbc profile, it will attempt to use the dev profile. Any thoughts on why that might be happening?

Comment: I have no idea why that is happening